# What do these nftables rules, as set up by wg-quick, mean?

Tags: wireguard, nftables

I am using `wg-quick` to open a VPN connection. I can see the utility is setting some `nft` rules and I would like to understand them. I have moderate knowledge of iptables but none of nftables.

Here is the Wireguard config file:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xxxxx
Address = 10.2.0.2/32
DNS = 10.2.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = yyyyyyyy
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 185.159.157.129:51820
```

When I invoke `wg-quick` I see this:

```
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.2.0.2/32 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] resolvconf -a tun.wg0 -m 0 -x
[#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
[#] nft -f /dev/fd/63
```

Here is a dump of the `nft` rules:

```
table ip wg-quick-wg0 {
        chain preraw {
                type filter hook prerouting priority raw; policy accept;
                iifname != "wg0" ip daddr 10.2.0.2 fib saddr type != local drop
        }

        chain premangle {
                type filter hook prerouting priority mangle; policy accept;
                meta l4proto udp meta mark set ct mark
        }

        chain postmangle {
                type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
                meta l4proto udp meta mark 0x0000ca6c ct mark set meta mark
        }
}
```

What do these `nft` rules mean, what are they for, and why are they needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st rule blocks inbound access to 10.2.0.2 from other interfaces and non local scoped addresses. Only accept packets from IP addresses directly accessed via interfaces of your computer. This for security,

2nd and 3rd are connection marking rules for policy routing wireguard's traffic. They tightly coupled with routing rule

```
ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
```

**With this rule all inbound and outbound traffic *not marked with 51820 routed* via wg0.**

But we need

- outgoing packets from wireguard itself routed to endpoint (remote peer) via main route table and **not** into the wg0 tunnel via 51820 table
  and
- incoming replies from remote wg peer routed to wireguard's process and **not** into the wg0 tunnel via 51820 table.

Wg marks their outgoing **packets** with 51820 value by iteslf by setting option with

```
wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
```

To distinguish incoming replie's packets from all other incoming packets we need to mark the whole wg's **connections** so we can restore same packet's mark for those incoming packets that "belongs" to these connections only.

3rd rule marks outgoing wireguard's **connections** wich **packets** have mark 51820 (0x0000ca6c in hex) with that mark so we can distinguish inbound replies of these connection with conntrack help.

2nd rule copies **connection's** mark back to **packet's** mark for all inbound packets.
So packets which are replies for outgoing wireguard's connections will have mark 51820 and will **not** routed into wg0 but routed to host itself.

Also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65178004/what-does-ip-4-rule-add-table-main-suppress-prefixlength-0-meaning

Checkout where routing is happend:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg